Can "put (someone) down" be used to mean "to kill a person" in a humurous context?
I have a line of dialogue in a scene I'm writing that is meant to be funny/humorous. Two people ride on horses, and one of them says as a joke:

“We have a long way ahead, and you’re already depleting our supplies.
Maybe I should put you down.”

Does it sound wierd when it's said to a person? What would be a good alternative?
Edit: they are close friends and they have a limited supply of food  and the joke is supposed to mean "although I really like you, I can't let you eat all of our food".

Really, you're asking if a perfectly understandable joke is 'appropriate'. That makes your question a matter of opinion. It must, surely, be less inappropriate than the one about the guy whose best friend, while peeing, gets bitten on the dick by a snake, and he calls 911, describes the snake, and the operator says 'suck the poison out at once, or death will occur in 30 minutes'. The guy says 'OK' and hangs up. 'What did they say?' asks the victim. 'They said you've got half an hour to live', his friend replies.

Feel free to use that. No charge.

Without any lead-in or context,  no. You can't "humorously" talk about killing the person you're riding with.
With context - perhaps.  "Put down" does mean to euthanise.  But its only used of animals.  I have seen jokes that use the ambiguity of "put down", but they are mostly used for the shock factor.
Is this a "real" problem in English? You seem to know the meaning of the word - but I can't imagine you actually wanting to suggest it, even humorously. It not bad English.  But it is a very very very bad joke.

The joke I've seen was about Derek Bentley, who was executed for murder after telling his child accomplice to "let him have it", which the accomplice took to mean "shoot him (the policeman)", but which could be taken to mean "give him the gun".  And the joke was saying "you can put down my puppy"

in the 1980s, an issue of the UK Daily Mail included a guide to filling in each household's Poll Tax registration form, which was supposed to include all residents at the address (for whom tax would be payable). The headline read 'What to do about Granny? Put her down."

It's dark humor and it's supposed to mean "although I really like you, I can't let you eat all of our food". But maybe you're right and the joke is inappropriate.
